# Which is the best way to incorporate custom fonts?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, css

I believe there are 3 valid methods of incorporating custom fonts:

1. put a link to them in the header
2. enqueue them in functions.php
3. add them with @font-face in style.css

Which is the best way to do it?
Is any method loading faster than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the source. If they are locally hosted, then they should be in the CSS files using @font-face. If they come from a service like Adobe Type Kit or Google Fonts, then they have to be enqueued in the functions.php to go into the wp_head() function.

Edit: I forgot to mention that there are some plugins that can handle this for you. I personally use Type Kit and I have seen WordPress plugins where you simply enter in the kit ID Adobe gives you and it takes care of insertion.